# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'A' was corrupted. Solution needed

Tags: c++, stack

I started to learn C++ and encounter a error.
I just create a class that produce a 10x10 matrix, put integers 0 to 99 into the matrix and print them out. However, it pop out a stack error with one of the value that supposed to be 93 become 0. I have no clue about it. Thank you for your answer.

```
//myclass.h
#pragma once

class Matrix {
private:
    int _2dmatrix [10][10];
public:
    Matrix ();
    ~Matrix ();
    void printMatrix ();
};

// myclass.cpp
#include "myclass.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            _2dmatrix[i+1][j+1] =i*10+j;
        }
}

Matrix::~Matrix () {}

void Matrix::printMatrix () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            cout << _2dmatrix[i+1][j+1] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

//source.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "myclass.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Matrix A;
    A.printMatrix();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays indexing starts at 0. `_2dmatrix[i+1][j+1]` this is going over array boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in C++ are zero-based. Simply change `i+1`to `i` and `j+1` to `j`.